# How to prevent my Google account from acting like it's from the US?

Tags: google-play-music, google

I'm from the Czech Republic and via some proxy I made my Google account look like a US-based one to try Google music etc. Now Google music with all access arrived in my country and it's cheaper than in the US! But Google remembers my account as being US-based so I still see the US price of $9.99.

Do you know how to change it back?

Comment: Is the proxy still on?

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing via Czech Republic - proxy and then try again. Good luck.

edit: Login with your credentials via proxy from Czech Republic and hope that the price will be different from the US price.

Comment: Your answer is rather short, I'm not really sure what you recommend to do. Could you edit your answer and be a little more verbose?

Comment: Login into Play Music with your credentials via proxy from Czech Republic and hope that the price will be different from the US price.